# Refused to execute script from '<URL>' after moving from dev to production

Tags: magento2, production-mode

When moved to production, with ***enabled js file bundling***, i start to get these types of errors in browser console:

```
Refused to execute script from 'http://ultra.com/static/frontend/RocketTeam/ultra/ru_RU/requirejs/require.min.js' because its MIME type ('text/html') is not executable, and strict MIME type checking is enabled.
```

Well, i check my files and it seems like i have them all in pub/static folder. So, for this *`http://ultra.com/static/frontend/RocketTeam/ultra/ru_RU/requirejs/require.min.js`* i have a file in my filesystem here:

```
magento/pub/static/frontend/RocketTeam/ultra/ru_RU/requirejs/require.js
```

When i try to reach these files via links from the browser console, i get 404.

As i understand my server returns me the wrong MIME type for js files. **But why this happens? In developer mode everything works fine.**

I just executed `php bin/magento deploy:mode:set production` and had output in the console similar to what is shown in documentation.

Magento 2.2 running locally in a docker container,
php 7.0.18

UPD: Ok, i was stupid, i don't have minified version of files in my filesystem. Ok, but why minification didn't happen?

UPD: Thanks to @PramodKharade, i managed to make it work.
What i did was:

after switching to production mode i cleaned and flushed caches, deleted generated folders, ran the setup, compiled code, and deployed static content:

1. rm -rf pub/static/*
2. rm -rf var
3. php bin/magento c:c
4. php bin/magento c:f
5. php bin/magento set:up
6. php bin/magento setup:di:compile
7. php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy --language ru_RU

Comment: After changing mode , first remove var,pub/static, generated folder then upgrade and deploy

Comment: @PramodKharade thanks for response. Could u please specify the step more clearly? I switched back to developer, then back to production, removed var and pub/static, ran magento setup:upgrade and then setup:static-content:deploy. I still have got some problems with loading requirejs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to @PramodKharade, I managed to make it work by performing the following steps:

**Steps:**

After switching to production mode I cleaned and flushed caches, deleted generated folders, ran the setup, compiled code, and deployed static content:

```
 1. rm -rf pub/static/*
 2. rm -rf var
 3. php bin/magento c:c
 4. php bin/magento c:f
 5. php bin/magento set:up
 6. php bin/magento setup:di:compile
 7. php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy --language ru_RU
```

Answer (score 1):

**1- At line no 10833**

```
tinymce.documentBaseURL = window.location.href.replace(/[\?#].*$/, '').replace(/[\/\\][^\/]+$/, '');
if (!/[\/\\]$/.test(tinymce.documentBaseURL))
tinymce.documentBaseURL += '/';
```

**Replace below Code**

```
tinymce.documentBaseURL = ADMIN_BASE_URL+"/tiny_mce";

tinymce.baseURL = ADMIN_BASE_URL+"/tiny_mce";

if(IS_MINIFY == 1) tinymce.suffix = '.min'; else tinymce.suffix = '';
```

**2- At line No 11391**

```
sl.add(tinymce.baseURL + '/langs/' + s.language + '.js');

Replace with

sl.add(tinymce.baseURL + '/langs/' + s.language + tinymce.suffix + '.js');
```

**3- Near at line No 10758**

```
tinymce.ScriptLoader.add(this.urls[n] + '/langs/' + s.language + '.js');

Replace with

tinymce.ScriptLoader.add(this.urls[n] + '/langs/' + s.language + tinymce.suffix + '.js');
```

**Override file in admin theme:**

> vendor/magento/module-backend/view/adminhtml/templates/page/js/require_js.phtml

**4- Find below code**

```
<script>

var BASE_URL = '<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $block->getUrl('*') ?>';

var FORM_KEY = '<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $block->getFormKey() ?>';

var require = {
"baseUrl": "<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $block->getViewFileUrl('/') ?>"
};
</script>
```

**Replace code with:**

```
<?php

$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();

$scopeConfig = $objectManager->create('Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface');

$isMinify = $scopeConfig->getValue('dev/js/minify_files', \Magento\Store\Model\ScopeInterface::SCOPE_STORE);    

?>

<script>

var BASE_URL = '<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $block->getUrl('*') ?>';

var FORM_KEY = '<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $block->getFormKey() ?>';

var ADMIN_BASE_URL = '<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $block->getViewFileUrl('/') ?>';

var IS_MINIFY = '<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $isMinify ?>';

var require = {
"baseUrl": "<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $block->getViewFileUrl('/') ?>"
};
</script>
```

**5- Run  below Commands**

> ```
> php bin/magento setup:upgrade
>
> php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy
> ```